# React native setState on new Object

Tags: react-native

I have a class `Two` with a bunch of functions inside. Some of them are using `this.setState({})` and they throw me a warning: `setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.`

Here's an example of the code:

```
class One extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.two = new Two;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.two.hello()
  }

  render() {
    return (<View><Text>Hello World!</Text></View>)
  }
}

class Two extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      connected: false
    }
  }

  hello() {
    this.setState({connected: true}) //This one throw the warning
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do things in a better way? Since my class `Two` is functionnal, I would like to not change the code too much to have things working. Btw, I need to the `this.two = new Two` line.

Should I create a library, a module, or whatever? If so, can you give me a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not mounting the Component, React can’t update it’s state using it’s built-in state handler.

And since you are not mounting it, it should probably not be a react component at all. Try using a regular class instead:

```
class Two {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      connected: false
    }
  }
  hello() {
    this.state.connected = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is you are trying to make components in React communicate in an unconventional way.

The way you want to go about this is to make use of props. This is how components talk to each other in React, instead of being direct, like you're attempting.

[Check out my code here where I'm doing the same as you](https://gist.github.com/WilliamIPark/a61dc2bb9a938a4e35a579b2aa45f7a2)

Basically, I've written 2 examples in 1 here. The first is passing just raw data through to another component. (`this.props.data.someData`). And the second, which is more like what you're wanting to do, is using [React's Life Cycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), to listen for when a function should run, through prop activation.

What this means in my example, is when the `runFunction` prop is passed into `Two`, either when it's first created `componentDidMount()` or when set to true later `componentWillRecieveProps()`, it will run the `testFunction()`